# Фильтрация массива целых чисел на C#, используя LINQ

Tags: linq, c#

Есть массив целых чисел:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 1, 9, 3, 2, 3, 5};
```

Как профильтровать этот массив, используя LINQ, так, чтобы в итоге остались только 3, идущие после 9?

```
int[] filtered = { 3, 3 };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[] filtered = numbers.SkipWhile(n => n != 9).Where(n => n == 3).ToArray();
```

Метод `SkipWhile` пропустит все элементы массива до девятки, а метод `Where` отберет все тройки из оставшихся.